# Как использовать метод другого класса

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть контроллер игрока. Нужно чтобы при пересечении коллайдера был вызван метод из класса Currency

```
public class Currency
{

    public class Gold
    {
        private int amountOfGold = 0;
        public void AddGold(int amountForAdd)
        {
            amountOfGold += amountForAdd;
        }
        public int ShowGold()
        {
            return amountOfGold;
        }
    }
}
```

Как я могу подключить класс Currency к другому скрипту без добавления как gameObject в инпекторе и тд, а чисто кодом.
Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: найди обьект по имени или тегу в старте или эвейке

Comment: @Andrew этот метод уже на всех сайтах видел ;)
Хочу узнать, как можно сделать это иным способом, помимо compareTag и Find

Comment: Например, скрипты могут общаться не напрямую, а через события 
( UnityEvents / Action ) Простейшую реализацию можно посмотреть здесь: https://github.com/ssa112112/WackyBreakout/tree/master/Assets/Scripts/Events

Comment: Кроме того, у вас может быть какой-то скрипт знающий о других. 
В простом варианте статичный Context, в котором будут лежать все "общие" скрипты (сам контекст их вполне может создавать или скрипты могут в нем "регистрироваться" при создании). В сложном можно прикрутить dependcy injection, например https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject

Comment: @SergeySkvortsov Благодарю <3

Comment: можно и не DI. Можно сделать в нужном объекте поле с типом Currency и с ним работать в нужный момент

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно просто использовать статику(конечно, если у вас один экземпляр Currency на весь проект)

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Currency GlobalCurrency;

    private void Awake()
    {
        GlobalCurrency = new Currency();
    }
}
```

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D
{
    Test.GlobalCurrency.gold.AddGold(gold);
}
```

UPD: Нежелательно вкладывать класс в класс, это очень некрасиво и неудобно.

Comment: Благодарю!
По поводу класс-класс задам вопрос.. лучше в таком случае использовать...структуры?

Comment: Если у вас будет что-то по типу "золото", "железо" и прочее, то рекомендую создать класс или структуру, которая будет иметь аналогичное строение, и создавать экземпляры класса по типу gold, iron, coal, milk и т.п. Если у вас просто золото, то выбор за вами, я бы просто вынес все переменные и функции и убрал класс gold, так как класс Currency предполагает наличие золота в валюте.